# How to do create description in jfreechart for z value?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I admit above question might be hard to understand, so let's start from beginning.
I created 3d block chart, values x,y are represented by point and z value is represented by colour.
Now, what i need is description somewhere on the side which colour represents which value, i saw sth like that in one of jfreechart example. so i know i might be done.
if anyone has done sth similar, could you give me hint how to achieve this? is it part of chart, or is it second chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can be done by adding one of the [PaintScale](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/PaintScale.html) implementations to your chart.

Comment: Just reference the same one used by your `XYBlockRenderer` when you paint your adjacent component.

Comment: Excellent! A `PaintScaleLegend ` is a `LegendTitle` that can be added to a chart.